# How can I Display 'Items per page' in pager instead of the exposed form

Tags: 7, views

I want to show 'Items per page' bellow the pager, I found [viewsxtras](http://drupal.org/project/viewsextras), but it's just a placeholder and does not contain any code.

I'm using drupal 7 and views 3.x.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

> [image]

In Drupal 7 under PAGER click on "Paged, xx items", then look at the Pager options window

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of the count in the aggrevation and then display it custom text in the footer region in the views. I have done it once, but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work with views exposed form

In .module file -> hook_form_alter

```
$pager_options = array(5, 10, 15, 20, 25);
$form['your-views-form-id'] = array(
  ‘#type’ => ‘select’,
  ‘#options’ => $pager_options,
  ‘#default_value’ => 0,
  ‘#title’ => t(‘Items per page’),
);


$pages = $pager_options[$form_state['input']['your-views-form-id']];
$form_state['view']->set_items_per_page($pages);
```

It will provide you a select box with the options you have given and you will be able select no. of items to display on result.